# code works in jags but not winbugs

Tags: jags, bugs

I have band-recovery data from several areas, and am trying to get survival rates for adult and juvenile for each area. Brownie model is used. The model is:

```
model {
# prior
for (k in 1:narea) {
  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    sj[k,t] ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    sa[k,t] ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    rj[k,t] ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    ra[k,t] ~ dbeta(1, 1)
  } # t
} # k

for (k in 1:narea) {
  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    marr.j[k,t,1:(nyr+1)] ~ dmulti(pr.j[k,t,], band.j[k,t])
    marr.a[k,t,1:(nyr+1)] ~ dmulti(pr.a[k,t,], band.a[k,t])
  } #t

  # juvenile
  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    pr.j[k,t,t] <- (1-sj[k,t])*rj[k,t]
    for (j in (t+2):nyr) {
      pr.j[k,t,j] <- sj[k,t]*prod(sa[k,(t+1):(j-1)])*(1-sa[k,j])*ra[k,j]
    } # j
    for (j in 1:(t-1)) {
      pr.j[k,t,j] <- 0
    } # j
  } # t

  for (t in 1:(nyr-1)) {
    pr.j[k,t,(t+1)] <- sj[k,t]*(1-sa[k,(t+1)])*ra[k,(t+1)]
  } # t

  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    pr.j[k,t,(nyr+1)] <- 1-sum(pr.j[k,t,1:nyr])
  } # t

  # adult
  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    pr.a[k,t,t] <- (1-sa[k,t])*ra[k,t]
    for (j in (t+1):nyr) {
      pr.a[k,t,j] <- prod(sa[k,t:(j-1)])*(1-sa[k,j])*ra[k,j]
    } # j
    for (j in 1:(t-1)) {
      pr.a[k,t,j] <- 0
    } # j
  } # t

  for (t in 1:nyr) {
    pr.a[k,t,(nyr+1)] <- 1-sum(pr.a[k,t,1:nyr])
  } # t
} # k
}    # model
```

The model works well in jags, but not in winbugs. When using winbugs, the following message was generated:

```
display(log)
check(d:/RESEARCH/A. waterfowl/4.survival/constant parameter.txt)
  model is syntactically correct
data(C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/data.txt)
data loaded
compile(3)
model compiled
inits(1,C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/inits1.txt)
      chain initialized but other chain(s) contain uninitialized variables
inits(2,C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/inits2.txt)
chain initialized but other chain(s) contain uninitialized variables
inits(3,C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/inits3.txt)
model is initialized
gen.inits()
command #Bugs:gen.inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
thin.updater(10)
update(10)
set(sj)
set(rj)
set(sa)
set(ra)
set(deviance)
dic.set()
command #Bugs:dic.set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
update(10)
coda(*,C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/coda)
command #Bugs:coda cannot be executed (is greyed out)
stats(*)
command #Bugs:stats cannot be executed (is greyed out)
dic.stats()

DIC
history(*,C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/history.odc)
command #Bugs:history cannot be executed (is greyed out)
save(C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/log.odc)
save(C:/Users/Qing/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcd452u/log.txt)
```

What could possibly be the reason for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: We can migrate this question to Stack Overflow for you but you will need to supply a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: JAGS manual lists differences between JAGS and BUGS so start with reviewing the differences. On the another hand your code does not include any sophisticated functions so it should work. A friend of mine once found an undocumented bug in WinBUGS - it appears that there are some low-level problems with arrays of three or more dimensions - so I would look for problems somewhere there.

Comment: looks like there is something going on with your initial values (or the ones that BUGS generates for you).